# Stripe payment integration with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, stripe-payments

im using the open source code https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe which is mentioned in firebase documentation, but I'm not able to run the above project successfully. When i deploy and visit index.html only user sign in is visible and the payment divs are not showing up.

As shown

[image]

And also this logs are being shown in firebase function console *DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead* . Can anyone please help me crack this.

Comment: See this posted [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/issues/120) regarding the warning.